# Usearch install error

Tags: bash, installation, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to run usearch through Ubuntu Bash (on Windows 10)I'm having real trouble in assigning it to the right path. This is the error I keep getting:

```
/usr/bin/usearch10.0.240_i86linux32: 1: /usr/bin/usearch10.0.240_i86linux32: Syntax error: "(" unexpected

error, no response from your usearch command (usearch10.0.240_i86linux32)
is it installed and in path?
```

Has anyone else had this problem?

Thanks

Rachel

Comment: What is the exact command you are trying to run?  Add it to the question, along with the different things you have tried so far.

Comment: That's `usearch` itself reporting an error in the input data. So you are looking in the wrong place: you have successfully run `usearch` (the pathname is correct) but *the data* given to `usearch` is incorrect.